# Visual Studio 2017 - stream analytics projects local run fails

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, asa

I am prototyping an ASA job with Visual Studio 2017.
I have created input and outputs and a ASA query.

This is the query, which I want to test. The query runs successfully in a productive environment and I wanted to test different input data.

```
SELECT
  System.TimeStamp cts,
  CONCAT(cast(event.p as nvarchar(max)),'_avg15') as p,
  event.p as pt,
  event.ttl,
  paraM.ArrayValue.mi,
  paraM.ArrayValue.pi,
  AVG(paraM.ArrayValue.v) as avg_v
INTO [docdbOutput]
FROM [iotinput] as event TIMESTAMP by event.cts
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.params) AS paraM
WHERE (paraM.ArrayValue.t = 1 and event.type = 4)
group by event.p,  event.ttl, paraM.ArrayValue.mi, paraM.ArrayValue.pi, 
      TumblingWindow(Duration(minute,15))
```

I have generated some test data too.
Executing locally the job fails with the error message "**Error: the accesss to the path "generated" was denied**"

Have a look at the output of the [locally executed job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzugh.png)

I am struggeling now for 2 hours and have no idea, what is wrong.
I think, the failure is caused by some settings of the "local executing" environment, but I have not found any hints how solve this issue.

In the past I had created an alternate ASA project, which is still working and generating output files (csv and json).
I have started VS 2017 as administrator and as user.

Any advice is welcome

Comment: Please take some time to read [how to ask](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [complete and verifiable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.
I opened my Visual Studio IDE in Administrator mode, and and now the project "runs locally" with local input and you created a query result.